# how to insert values to xml variable using python

Tags: python, xml

i have xml (template) file and i set variables in the xml using {$var}

and i have a list with values for the xml variables.

how can i open (set) my file and set the xml variable to the values
from my list ?

```
<sut>
    <Cdu>
        <class>XXX</class>
        <conn>
            <class>XXX</class>
            <cli>
                <password>{$password}</password>
                <user>{$user}</user>
                <host>{$host}</host>
                <connectOnInit>false</connectOnInit>
            </cli>
        </conn>
        <basic>
            <class>XXX</class>
        </basic>
    </Cdu>
```

Comment: Have a look at the Mako template framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use f string?

```
password = 'secret'
user = 'jack'
host = '12.56.78.123'
xml = f'''<sut>
    <Cdu>
        <class>XXX</class>
        <conn>
            <class>XXX</class>
            <cli>
                <password>{password}</password>
                <user>{user}</user>
                <host>{host}</host>
                <connectOnInit>false</connectOnInit>
            </cli>
        </conn>
        <basic>
            <class>XXX</class>
        </basic>
    </Cdu>'''
print(xml)
```

output

```
<sut>
    <Cdu>
        <class>XXX</class>
        <conn>
            <class>XXX</class>
            <cli>
                <password>secret</password>
                <user>jack</user>
                <host>12.56.78.123</host>
                <connectOnInit>false</connectOnInit>
            </cli>
        </conn>
        <basic>
            <class>XXX</class>
        </basic>
    </Cdu>
```

Comment: He has `<password>{$password}</password>` in input not `<password>{password}</password>`

Comment: The question is - can he control the template and modify it. If he can - f string is a perfect win, else - we need more complex solution. @undertale - do you have control over the "template"?

Comment: good news - just use my code and you are done :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for this task following way

```
import re
txt = '''<password>{$password}</password>
<user>{$user}</user>
<host>{$host}</host>'''
data = {"password": "SECRET", "user": "NAME", "host": "LOCAL"}
def replacement(x):
    return data[x.group(1)]
out = re.sub(r'\{\$([^\}]+)\}', replacement, txt)
print(out)
```

output

```
<password>SECRET</password>
<user>NAME</user>
<host>LOCAL</host>
```

Explanation: `re.sub` second argument might be function which accept Match object. I used regular expression with one capturing group, which content I then use to look up data `dict`. Note that `{` and `$` and `}` need escaping as these have special meaning, but we need literal `{` and `$` and `}`. Disclaimer: I used substring of original for brevity sake.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Template class from standard `string` module:

```py
from string import Template


password = 'secret'
user = 'jack'
host = '12.56.78.123'

xml_template = '''<sut>
    <Cdu>
        <class>XXX</class>
        <conn>
            <class>XXX</class>
            <cli>
                <password>${password}</password>
                <user>${user}</user>
                <host>${host}</host>
                <connectOnInit>false</connectOnInit>
            </cli>
        </conn>
        <basic>
            <class>XXX</class>
        </basic>
    </Cdu>'''

xml = xml_template.substitute(password=password, user=user, host=host)
print(xml)
```

There are also `safe_substitute` method that may be used in case you are not sure about context variables.