# To print the data after replacing the given expression with the values in XML file using "ElementTree" library

Tags: python, json, xml, elementtree

Given XML file snippet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<event_configuration family="21" version="2">
    <pqr subtype="abc">
    <event val="73002" name="$MyCpu"> </event>
    <event val="73003" name="$MyCpuKernel"> </event>

    <metric name="Ratio" expression="$MyCpuKernel / $MyCpu"> </metric>
    </pqr>
</event_configuration>
```

I have parsed this xml file using "ElementTree" library in Python, please find the code below:

```
    def parse_xml_to_json(self):
        data = {'metric': []}
        root = ET.fromstring(self.xml_file)

        for element in root.findall('.//*'):
            element_type = element.tag
            if element_type not in ["pqr", "stu", "vwx"]:
                continue
            subtype_name = element.attrib['subtype']
            event_map = {}
            for event in element.findall('.//event'):
                event_name = event.attrib['name']
                val_value = event.attrib['val']
                event_map[event_name] = val_value

            for metric in element.findall('metric'):
                expression = metric.attrib['expression']
                metric_name = metric.attrib['name']
          
                for event_name, val_value in event_map.items():
                    expression = expression.replace(event_name, val_value)

                data['metric'].append({
                    'Name': metric_name,
                    'Expression': expression,
                    'Type': element_type
                })

        return data
```

I am getting the output, but this code is unable to replace the event name present inside "Expression" with the val_value as shown below:-

Output:

```
{
"metric": [
    {
        "Name": "Ratio",
        "Expression": "73002Kernel / 73002",
        "Type": "pqr"
    },
    ....
    ....
]
}
```

Here, we can see in the "Expression" it should print "73003 / 73002".
I am unable to think of how to solve this issue. Is it possible to use regex here, how to apply it? Please suggest.

Comment: It is a task for XSLT with parameters

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68359528/how-to-insert-values-to-xml-variable-using-python) your question?

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with json? Your return data is type class dict not json. Maybe wrong tag or you miss some information in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how you can use `re.sub` to replace the values in expression:

```py
import re
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def parse_xml_to_json(xml_file):
    data = {"metric": []}
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_file)

    for element in root.findall(".//*"):
        element_type = element.tag
        if element_type not in ["pqr", "stu", "vwx"]:
            continue
        subtype_name = element.attrib["subtype"]
        event_map = {}
        for event in element.findall(".//event"):
            event_name = event.attrib["name"]
            val_value = event.attrib["val"]
            event_map[event_name] = val_value

        for metric in element.findall("metric"):
            expression = metric.attrib["expression"]
            metric_name = metric.attrib["name"]

            for event_name, val_value in event_map.items():
                expression = re.sub(
                    rf"{re.escape(event_name)}\b", val_value, expression
                )

            data["metric"].append(
                {"Name": metric_name, "Expression": expression, "Type": element_type}
            )

    return data


xml_file = """\
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<event_configuration family="21" version="2">
    <pqr subtype="abc">
    <event val="73002" name="$MyCpu"> </event>
    <event val="73003" name="$MyCpuKernel"> </event>

    <metric name="Ratio" expression="$MyCpuKernel / $MyCpu"> </metric>
    </pqr>
</event_configuration>"""

print(parse_xml_to_json(xml_file))
```

Prints:

```py
{'metric': [{'Name': 'Ratio', 'Expression': '73003 / 73002', 'Type': 'pqr'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the XML and create than your JSON. The XML attribute values can be `.get()` and `.set()` For the expression attribute you can use an `f-string` with the values:

Suggested solution in your code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Whatever:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xml_file = "eventConfig.xml"
    
    def parse_xml_to_json(self):
        data = {'metric': []}
        root = ET.parse(self.xml_file) # cahnged parse from file not from string

        for element in root.findall('.//*'):
            element_type = element.tag
            if element_type not in ["pqr", "stu", "vwx"]:
                continue
            subtype_name = element.attrib['subtype']
            event_map = {}
            
            for metric in element.findall('metric'):
                expression = metric.attrib['expression']
                metric_name = metric.attrib['name']

            mycpu = root.find(".//event[@name = '$MyCpu']").get('val')
            mycpukernel = root.find(".//event[@name = '$MyCpuKernel']").get('val')
            tex = f"{mycpu}/{mycpukernel}"
            #metric = root.find(".//metric[@expression]").set('expression', tex)

            data['metric'].append({
                'Name': metric_name,
                'Expression': tex,
                'Type': element_type
            })

        return data
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Whatever()
    res = p.parse_xml_to_json()
    print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'metric': [{'Name': 'Ratio', 'Expression': '73002/73003', 'Type': 'pqr'}]}
```

Comment: Just a nitpick; at no point are you working with JSON in this code. You've got xml element classes and python objects (dictionaries and lists) but no JSON. You don't want to mix those terms since they are very different things.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, the OP ask for the XML parsing part with ElementTree, isn't it.

Comment: Yeah but that has nothing to do with JSON. Again, at no point in the code you've posted are you working with JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). It's all python in the code you've posted minus the xml doc it reads and writes.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, again I don’t know what you would like to say, sorry. Again the question is about print out of parsed xml. Show your answer, if you know it better!

Comment: Again, it's a nitpick. I'm not saying the answer is wrong but the reference to JSON is wrong as you aren't doing anything with JSON in your code.

Comment: @MatthewGreen, than the tagging is wrong. No one speaks about jason, expecting you.

Comment: @Hermann12 I think what Mathew Green is trying to say: your answer states "You can change the XML and create than your JSON." If you are not creating JSON then that sentence is not correct.